# How to change arrow function to normal function that it works in Internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am using following code on chrome and firefox.

It works well but because of two arrow function in javascript, animations do not work on Internet explorer.

How should I write them as normal function in javascript?

Thanks in advance

A Demo you can find here
https://jsfiddle.net/80vr25zf/

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.evyt_.h-counter');    
counters.forEach(counter => {
const updateCount = () => {
const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
const count = +counter.innerText;
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not the only thing that doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Just use a normal function then?! There's nothing in your code that needs arrow-specific features.

Comment: add `function` in front, make sure the parameter (if any) is in brackets, remove the `=>`. Done.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, ES6 features ( Inculding arrow and anonymous functions ) are not implemented in IE 11.

So you should use the classic function declaration supported by ES5 ( hence Internet Explorer )

You code will look like below :

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.evyt_.h-counter');    
counters.forEach(function counterFunction(counter) {
const updateCount = function updateCode() {
const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
const count = +counter.innerText;  }}
```

Comment: [Ouch ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: @Teemu I assume [you're referring to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Comment: @Teemu But as he mentioned arrow function didn't work on IE, Does this make my answer irrelevant ? Thank you!

Comment: No, not at all, it just is not complete. @VLAZ Yep, just missed that the method has its own page too.

Comment: "*ES6 features ( Inculding arrow and anonymous functions )*", wait, how can anonymous functions not be supported? I don't see anything about this in the table and I am confident that IE works with them.